# How can I pass a div as a parameter to jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

Is there a way to pass an entire div as a parameter to a jQuery dialog ?

For instance the code below shows what happens when I click ok on a dialog, I am already passing a data attribute to the dialog which i can use to get some elements values by their classes. I am then passing those to my ajax functions as parameters...

I want to pass the entire div instead of fetching each element within it by the class, because this current function is is to carry out some **adding** routine, i want to use the same ajax routine for doing an **update**, so if i can pass the div as a parameter, i can fetch its content within my ajax function.

`Click` function:

```
$(".btnAddCommunity").click(function () {
    var emptyGuid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
    $(".dvCommunityDialog").data("communityId", emptyGuid).dialog("open");
});
```

Dialog:

```
$(".dvCommunityDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 'auto',
    title: "Interests and Online Community",
    width: 600,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        OK: function () {
            var communityName = $(".txtCommunityName").val();
            var communityDescription = $(".txtCommunityDescription").val();
            var communityLink = $(".txtCommunityLink").val();
            var communityId = $(".dvCommunityDialog").data("communityId");
            var dvOnlineCommunityMain = $("#dvOnlineCommunityMain");
            dvOnlineCommunityMain.append("<p>Test</p>");
            UpdateOnlineCommunity(communityId, communityName, communityDescription, communityLink);
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
});
```

Ajax Request function:

```
function UpdateOnlineCommunity(communityId, communityName, communityDescription, communityLink) {
var serviceData = JSON.stringify({
    'communityId': communityId,
    'communityName': communityName,
    'communityDescription': communityDescription,
    'communityLink': communityLink
});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PresentationService.asmx/UpdateUserCommunity",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: serviceData,
    success: function(response) {
        var data = response.d;

        var dvOnlineCommunityMain = $(".dvOnlineCommunityMain");

        var dvOnlineCommunity = $('<div/>', {
            id: "dvOnlineCommunity",
            class: "dvOnlineCommunity",
            "data-id": data.CommunityID
        });

        var lblOnlineCommunityDescription = $('<span/>', {
            id: "lblOnlineCommunityDescription",
            text: data.Description
        });

        var pOnlineCommunityDetails = $('<p/>', {
            id: "pOnlineCommunityDetails",
            text: data.Detail
        });

        var linkOnlineCommunity = $('<a/>', {
            id : "linkOnlineCommunity",
            href : data.Link,
            text: data.Link
        });

        var paragraph = $('<p></p>');

        var btnUpdateOnlineCommunity = $('<button/>', {
            id: "btnUpdateOnlineCommunity",
            class: "btnUpdateOnlineCommunity",
            text: "Update"
        });

        var btnDeleteOnlineCommunity = $('<button/>', {
            id: "btnDeleteOnlineCommunity",
            class: "btnUpdateOnlineCommunity",
            text: "Delete"
        });


        dvOnlineCommunity.append(lblOnlineCommunityDescription, pOnlineCommunityDetails, linkOnlineCommunity,
            btnUpdateOnlineCommunity, btnDeleteOnlineCommunity);

        dvOnlineCommunityMain.append(dvOnlineCommunity);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: to be used as the content? can you explain why you'd want this to do and show your code

Comment: @atmd updated with codes

Comment: wouldn't it just be a matter of updating `UpdateOnlineCommunity` to take the parent element of its existing parameters and pass that through? maybe I'm missing something, but the dialog isn't doing anything with the element, you are passing them to another function

Comment: @atmd i wrote in there, the dialog will be doing something with the div element when doing an update... At the moment the code above is only working for sending new values through to the database....BUT when updating, i need to read the values of the div childs into the dialog control to display their initial value before change, then after a change, send the values through my web service, then update the same div after a success response.. if you have the solution can you please paste it. thank you